# Custom SharePoint List forms in SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jslink, sharepoint-framework

We are migrating old SharePoint 2010 On Premise code to SharePoint Online. Part of the SharePoint 2010 on premise code has **custom list forms** developed with visual Studio.

Thought of using **JSLink** for custom forms while migrating the code to SharePoint Online but it seems that JSLink is only supported in classic experience and **not in modern new experience**.

Is there any way we can develop custom list forms on SharePoint Online with modern new experience? Is it possible with SharePoint Framework?

**Note:** Tried by adding forms to list instances on SharePoint Hosted Add In but it targets the AppWeb lists and not the lists on HostWeb.

Answer (score 1):

There are no options to modify forms in modern experience other than [PowerApps](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/) or [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/sharepoint-forms/) so far. I'm a developer of the second tool and can say that it provides a lot of customization features - you can adjust your form with CSS, develop own controls and fields with JavaScript in a similar way to JSLink. Also, it has several advanced controls e.g. List or Library for editing related items/documents from another list, Ink Sketch for leaving hand-written notes in a form, Data Table for adding table-oriented data and some others.